# Best way to schedule jobs in production

Tags: scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

I'm curious as to what the best way to schedule jobs in production is?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

I want to schedule a job to run every hour, which I can't do through the UI unless I create 24 different jobs.  If I schedule it through code, like in their example:

```
proschedule p = new proschedule();
String sch = '0 0 8 13 2 ?';
system.schedule('One Time Pro', sch, p);
```

I would need some way to run this code.  "Open Execute Anonymous Window" is disabled in our production environment.  Is the best way to run this scheduling to enable the Apex Author permisson on the profile and use the developer console, or is there a better way of running code that schedules a job.

Comment: Yeah you need `Author Apex` permission unless you hook this up to a front end. Like you could expose it via `Visualforce` or lightning

Comment: Is the best way to run this scheduling to enable the Apex Author permisson on the profile? You can use a permission set in case you do not want to enable at the profile level.

Comment: I'm more asking is the dev console the best approach, or is there another approach.  Granting the permissions wouldn't be an issue per se.